# Showing content below Supersized slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, supersized

I'm trying to show content below a full-screen slideshow that behaves normally.  Only when you scroll down should the remaining content be revealed. So on load the slideshow should still be 100% in height and width.

I tried put a margin top that is the same size as the browser height (detected with js) and put the slideshow position absolute but that did not work ...

Would love to hear your thoughts on this, thanks a lot!

example: http://www.fabrikgrafik.be/slider/
(I'm trying to get the red content div below the slideshow without losing the slideshow functionality)

Comment: Put your slide show controls and background in a div, set it to `position: fixed;` and `z-index: -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple, don't change anything from what it was aminute ago except to add the following 2 lines of jQuery:

```
// made edit to hide content till slideshow is rdy
$("#content-wrapper").css("margin-top", $("#supersized").height()).show();
$(window).resize(function(e) { $("#content-wrapper").css("margin-top", $("#supersized").height()); });
```

## updated jsFiddle

Also, you might change this CSS:

```
#controls-wrapper { display: none; position: absolute; } /* from fixed */
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not my problem. This I can do :). The problem is, I would like the red (content) div to start where the slideshow ends.

So now it loads full width and height and when I scroll it is doing exactly what I want. but the red div should start below the slideshow and not over it. So I think I have to put a margin-top on "content-wrapper" that has the same size as the browser-height. But I'm not sure how to do this and if this is the right solution.

thanks again

Comment: made it couple changes, looks great

Comment: Thanks so much! I was really breaking my head about this :). this is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Happy I not have to change my design.

Comment: Jquery is not necessary, its a simple css solution... http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/9wCHZ/

Comment: @VIDesignz that doesnt work on his sight because of a few other elements at play, but the jquery is short and simple. I already tried just a pure css change, but it involved changing several items, jQuery was just easier

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out....css style

```
 #redDivId {position:absolute; top:100%;}
```

Check out this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/9wCHZ/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is indeed true and what I am trying to accomplish. But now only the red div should start exactly where the bottom of the slideshow ends. Just under the "fold". And this where I can not succeed.

Comment: I don't see you js to position the red div on the page? where is it at?

Comment: I see this **<div id="content-wrapper" style="margin: auto; width: 960px; opacity: 0.5; clear: both; background: red; color: #FFFFFF;">** but no margin-top declaration.

Comment: No indeed, I have took this out because I was doing it wrong :). But I'm also not sure if this is the right way to go, maybe there is a css only solution I'm not seeing.

Comment: @fabrikgrafik Dude you don't need jquery for this!!

Comment: cheers man, less jquery is always better! I'm going to clean up the code of this experiment now and start the project. Thanks for helping me out.